# How do I get the subset of a collection of elements using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, set

I'm new to language. I was just wondering if there is any class for finding the collection of objects in Java like Python does, or I have to write program myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a universal class for finding information, and it is called Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binary numbers to find the sets of an array element.
Check [this github repository](https://github.com/prashantghimire/Array-Elements-and-String-Character-Combination-with-Binary-Numbers-using-Java).
Here is how you do it.

```
String [] collection = {"Apple","Banana","Carrot"};
        printArray(itemCombinator(collection));


public static void printArray(String[] toPrint){
        System.out.println("Combination Result:");
        for (int i = 0; i < toPrint.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(toPrint[i]);
        }
    }


public static String[] itemCombinator(String[] array){
        int len = array.length;
        String [] resultArray;
        String result = "";
        int [][] bin = binaries(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
            String comb= "";
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                if(bin[i][j] == 1){
                    comb+=array[j]+" ";
                }
            }
            result += comb+"-";
        }
        resultArray = result.split("-");
        return resultArray;
    }
```